# Checking whether object has changed (preserving good class design)

Tags: java, object-oriented-analysis

I have objects called "hierarchies", basically just a list of strings, eg. [1 2 3 4]. I also have objects called FormattedHierarchies that should always keep a formatted version of the hierarchy in the way the user wants them represented, e.g. (1-4) or {1,2,3,4}.

My problem is this:

I want to update the FormattedHierarchy immediately when the Hierarchy has been changed (e.g. if the Hierarchy changes from [1 2 3 4] to [1 2 3] the FormattedHierarchy should change from (1-4) to (1-3)).

Googling turned up the http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/changelistener.html
but my problem is this: if I want to have Hierarchy implement the ChangeListener, it has to implement the method "stateChanged".

> The type Hierarchy must implement the inherited abstract method 
>        ChangeListener.stateChanged(ChangeEvent)

Having the Hierarchy create a new FormattedHierarchy is not feasible and I'm also thinking that this is not good class design. This is because the Hierarchy would then implement stuff that deals with its formatting (albeit in an indirect way).

Are there any standard or clever solutions to this problem?

Comment: why not just use a flag (e.g. `isModified`)?

Comment: As I want the changes to be automatically updated I would rather have a isChanged-method that is called whenever a setter is used on the hierarchy. It might have implications I am not aware of or can't foresee Are there any downsides to having the setter call a isChanged-method whenever the setter is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to avoid the need to have two objects kept exactly in sync. I can suggest you three ways:

1. Have whoever is calling the `Hierarchy` setter call also a `refresh()` method on `FormattedHierarchy`. This is easy if you call the setter from one or really few places.
2. Recalculate the String representation of `Hierarchy` only on demand, without storing it. You need to store the format, not the actual formatted result.
3. Have `Hierarchy` maintain a *version count*, which is incremented every time you change it. `FormattedHierarchy` holds the formatted string, and the last version count it has seen. When you ask `FormattedHierarchy` for the string, it first checks if the version count has changed, triggering a recalc of the formatted string if case it did.

Comment: Appreciate the answer- all ways will likely be of help to others looking up related questions. If anybody comes up with additions to the list, please comment. Edit: what is wrong with having two objects exactly in sync?

Comment: I'm not sure it's bad, but in my experience it's a pain. And it's really bad for multithreading, in case you start needing it.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply merge `Hierarchy` class with `FormattedHierarchy`, using if needed two distinct Interfaces for your distinct consumers?

By this way, you would only have to create specific setters in your class that will modify both strings `[1 2 3 4]` and `(1-4)` to `[1 2 3]` and `(1-3)` when a set is done.

Comment: This has its merits as I would only need one setter, but I am not too keen on merging data and representation.